# One or two controller for users login and users crud

Tags: php, authentication, crud

how is better for organize:

One Users controller with methods:

- login/logout/account/forgetpassword
- create/edit/delete (only for admin user)

Or two controllers:

- User.php with methods login/logout/account/forgetpassword
- Users.php (or other name) with methods create/edit/delete (only for admin user)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Two controllers, one for Login, other for Users, regarding each scope. Login controller will extends from User controller. And ONE model, called User model.